# Как вывести Label над Canvas?

Tags: delphi

Задачу поставили максимально из стандартных компонетов и элементов, сделать "красиво".

Сделал из мемо бокс с раскрывающимися панельками, закрасил им Canvas, чтоб однородно, но добавив в панель Label чтоб хоть что-то туда писать, Label с текстом отображается под канвасом и никаких надписей не видно. Как вытащить надпись наверх? Писать на канвасе снаружи будет ой как неудобно...

```
 unit ToggledPanels;   
    interface

uses
Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type


TstorageMemo = class(TMemo)
private
{ Private declarations }
   PCount: word; {количество Toggl-ов}
   procedure PPanelCount(Count:word);{заводим количество панелей}
   procedure WMPaint(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_Paint;{отрисовка}
protected
{ Protected declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
   TGLineHeight: Word;
published
{ Published declarations }
    property PanelCount: word write PPanelCount;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
end;

TToggledLabel = class;

TToggledPanel = class(TPanel){сами панельки}
private
  Opened: boolean;{статус открыт/закрыт}
  TGLineHeight: Word;{пока не используется, высота тогла}
  ToglText:TToggledLabel;{сюда будем снаружи пихать текст в лэйбл}
{ Private declarations }
  procedure WMPaint(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_Paint;
protected
{ Protected declarations }
public
 // Width: word;
{ Public declarations }
published
{ Published declarations }

   destructor Destroy; override;
   constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
   procedure Click; override;
end;

TToggledLabel = class(TLabel)
private
  { Private declarations }
 protected
{ Protected declarations }
public
 // Width: word;
{ Public declarations }
published
{ Published declarations }
end;

implementation

var
 CountBuf : array of TToggledPanel;{храним количество тогглов}

{ TstorageMemo }

constructor TstorageMemo.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
   inherited;
   Self.Cursor:= crArrow;{начальные конструкции}
   Self.Top:= 40;
   Self.Left:= 40;
   Self.Height:= 200;
   Self.Width:= 500;
   Self.ScrollBars:= ssVertical;
   Self.Ctl3D:=false;
   Self.ReadOnly:=true;
end;

procedure TstorageMemo.PPanelCount(Count: word);
var
   i: word;
begin
    inherited; { собственно создадим и забьем панельками}
   setlength(CountBuf, Count);
   PCount:=Count;
   if Count>0 then
   for i := 1 to Count do begin
   CountBuf[i]:= TToggledPanel.Create(Self);
   CountBuf[i].Parent:= Self;
   CountBuf[i].AutoSize:=false;
   CountBuf[i].Width:=Self.Width;
   CountBuf[i].TGLineHeight:=20;
   CountBuf[i].Name:='TogglePanel'+inttostr(i);
   if i > 1 then
     CountBuf[i].Top:=20*(i-1)
      else CountBuf[i].Top:=0;
   end;
end;

procedure TstorageMemo.WMPaint(var Msg: TMessage);
var
   i: word;
begin

    HideCaret(Self.Handle);{прячем каретку в мемо, она не нужна}
    for i := 1 to length(CountBuf) do begin{и закрашиваем после раскрытия} тогла
    if i > 1 then   begin
      CountBuf[i].Top:=CountBuf[i-1].Height+CountBuf[i-1].Top+2;
      CountBuf[i].ToglText.BringToFront;{попытка выдернуть лэйбл наверх/не работает}
    end
      else CountBuf[i].Top:=0;
   end;

  inherited;
end;

constructor TToggledPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin


inherited;
   Self.Height:=20;
   Self.Opened:= false;
   Self.Caption:='';
   Self.AutoSize:=True;
   Self.ParentShowHint:=false;
   Self.ParentColor:=false;
   Self.ParentCustomHint:=false;
   {выставили параметры при создании, теперь создадим внутри лейбл}
   ToglText:= TToggledLabel.Create(Self);
   ToglText.Parent:= Self;
   ToglText.BringToFront;
   with ToglText do begin
   Top:=20+5;
   AutoSize:=true;
   Width:=Self.Width-20;
   Height:=40;
   Left:=10;
{текст для примера}
       Text:='11111111111111111'+#13#10+'2222222222222'+#13#10+'333333333333';
   ParentFont:=true;
   ParentColor:=False;
   end;

end;

destructor TToggledPanel.Destroy;
begin
   inherited;
end;

procedure TToggledPanel.WMPaint(var Msg: TMessage);

begin

      inherited;
{заливка после раскрытия}
        with Self.Canvas do  begin
          Brush.Color:= $00f4a142;
         end;
         ExtFloodFill(Self.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, $00f4a142, FLOODFILLBORDER);

end;

destructor TstorageMemo.Destroy;
var
   i: word;
begin
  for i := 1 to PCount do CountBuf[i].Destroy;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TToggledPanel.Click;
var
   i: word;
   t:byte;
begin

{тут собственно раскрытие}
  if self.Opened then
  begin
  self.Height:= self.Height div 7;
  self.Opened:=false;
  end
  else   begin
  i:=self.Height*7;
  t:=0;
  while self.Height<i do begin
    Self.Height:=Self.Height+(t div 2);
    inc(t);
    sleep(10);
    Self.ToglText.BringToFront;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
   Self.ToglText.BringToFront;
  self.Opened:=true;
  end;
  inherited;
end;


end.
```

На форму добавить

```
procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ToggledPanel:= TstorageMemo.Create(Form3);
   ToggledPanel.Parent:= Form3;
   ToggledPanel.PanelCount:=2;
   ToggledPanel.TGLineHeight:=20;
end;
```

Вариант черновой, поэтому размеры, св-ва, пар-ры, и т.п. в большом количестве пока изнутри выставляются...Не обращайте внимания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TLabel` - наследуется от `TControl`-а, своего хэндла (HWND) у него нет, он рисуется на `HDC` родителя и перекрывается любым `TWinControl`-ом на том же родителе. `TPanel` - наследник `TWinControl`-a, со своим хэндлом и контекстом рисования.

Используйте `TStaticText`, который является наследником `TWinControl`-a.

Comment: Спасибо, как сам не допер за 10 часов.... А подскажите пожалуйста, `TStaticText` - это стандартный? Просто условие такое поставили чтоб всё из стандартных

Comment: @Сергей Да, это стандартный Delphi-евский контрол.

Comment: хмм...вопрос может неможко не в тему, а с помощью `NeedHandle` или т.п. команд, нельзя `label`-у заполучить handle?

Comment: @Сергей, `TLabel` есть *графический* компонент - он не имеет собственного `Handle`, соответственно, получить его **абсолютно невозможно**. Вам уже дали ответ с рекомендацией использовать `TStaticText`, обладающий собственным `Handle`. Если существует непреодолимая тяга к использованию `TLabel`, то единственный выход - перерисовывать `TLabel` после каждой отрисовки панелей, что будет весьма и весьма муторно.

Comment: @Сергей, на заметку: компонент `TPanel` имеет свойство `Caption`. Возможно, получится использовать его без увеличения количества компонентов.

Comment: @Dima, быстрее оказалось написать свой `TGraphicsControl` под свои задачи))

Answer (score -1):

Никак, лейбел может лежать только на картинке или форме. Я же просто заносил лейблы в массив и еще 1 делал f [1..n] array of bolean записывал их значения при кликах. Дальше делал динамично кнопки 0х0 и записывал на них код. Но это уже надстройка и т.д.